# How to parse error message sent from server in Angular Component?

Tags: angular, http-post

Here is my backend code

```
if (err)
            {
              res.status(400).send({ error: "invalid credentials", data: null, message: "Invalid Credentials" });

            }
            else
            {

                res.status(200).send({ data: user });
            }
```

Here is my Angular Code

```
 let obj = { "name": name, "email": email, "password": password };

  this.http.post("https://localhost:3000/register",obj, {responseType: 'json'})
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
        },
        error => {

            console.log(error); 

        }
    );
```

I'm able to log the error object. I need to get the exact error message which is passed from the backend.

Something like this

```
 console.log(error.message);
```

I tried it, but I'm getting an error. What is the right way to parse the HttperrorResponse in Angular JS?

Comment: can you post the error from the console?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from my code that works fine :

```
this.protocolListService.versionWorkspaceId
      .subscribe(res => {
        if(!!res){
          this.projectService.getGeoJsonFromWorkspaceId(res)
          .subscribe(
            res => {
              if(!!res){
                this.editElements = JSON.parse(res.body.pgjGeojson);
              }
            },
            err => {
              console.log("Error > " + err);
              this.editElements = new Workspace();
            },
            () => console.log("Unspecified error")
          );
        }
      });
```

I believe you should change `error` with `err` instead

Comment: change error with err --> it's just a callback and it can be anything

Answer (score 0):

Just check if error is of instance type HttpErrorResponse and parse

```
this.http.post("https://localhost:3000/register",obj, {responseType: 'json'})
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
            },
            error => {
              if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log('message', error.message);
              }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `console.log(error.error.message)` to log the actual error message.

Refer: [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse)